# Não estou conseguindo redenrizar o componente da biblioteca RecyclerListView react-native com expo

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, listview, expo

estou tentando renderizar um componente da biblioteca RecyclerListView e escrevi o seguinte codigo:

```
 import { useContext } from 'react';
import { Dimensions, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { RecyclerListView, LayoutProvider } from 'recyclerlistview';

import { AudioContext } from '../../src/context/AudioProvaider';

interface ItemRow {
  filename: String;
}

export default function TabOneScreen() {

  const { audioFiles, dataProvaider } = useContext(AudioContext);
  
  console.log(dataProvaider)

  const LayoutProvaider = new LayoutProvider((i) =>'audio', (type, dim) => {
    switch (type) {
      case 'audio': 
        dim.width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
        dim.height = 70;
        break;
      default:
        dim.height = 0;
        dim.width = 0;
    }
});

const RowRender = ((type: string | number, item: ItemRow) => {
  console.log(item)
  return <Text>{item.filename}</Text>
})

  return (
    <AudioContext.Consumer>
      {({ dataProvaider }) => (
        <RecyclerListView 
          dataProvider={dataProvaider}
          layoutProvider={LayoutProvaider}
          rowRenderer={RowRender}
        />
      )}
    </AudioContext.Consumer>
  );
}
```

e um contexto:

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useState, ReactNode } from 'react';
import { Alert } from 'react-native';
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';
import { DataProvider } from 'recyclerlistview';

interface Audio {
    id: String;
    url: String;
}

interface PlayList {}

interface AudioProvaiderTypes {
    audioFiles: Audio[];
    dataProvaider: any;
}

export const AudioContext = createContext<AudioProvaiderTypes>({} as AudioProvaiderTypes)

export function AudioProvaider({ children }: {children: ReactNode }) {

    const [audioFiles, setAudioFiles] = useState<Audio[]>([]);
    const [PermissionError, setPermissionError] = useState(false);
    const [dataProvaider, setDataProvaider] = useState(new DataProvider((r1, r2) => r1 !== r2));

    useEffect(() => {
        getPermission();
    }, []);

    const permissionAlert = () => {
        Alert.alert('Permission required', 'this app needs to read audio files from device', [{
            text: 'I am ready',
            onPress: () => getPermission()
        }, {
            text: 'cancelar',
            onPress: () => permissionAlert()
        }]);
    };

    const getAudioFiles = async () => {
        let media = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({
            mediaType: 'audio',
        });

        media = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({
            mediaType: 'audio',
            first: media.totalCount
        });

        setDataProvaider( dataProvaider.cloneWithRows([...audioFiles, ...media.assets]));
        setAudioFiles([...audioFiles, ...media.assets]);
    };

    const getPermission = async () => {
        const permission = await MediaLibrary.getPermissionsAsync();

        if (permission.granted) {
            // get all files audio
            getAudioFiles();
        }

        if (!permission.granted && permission.canAskAgain) {
            const { status, canAskAgain } = await MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync();

            if (status === 'danied' && canAskAgain) {
                permissionAlert();
            }

            if (status === 'granted') {
                //get all audio files
                getAudioFiles();
            }

            if (status === 'danied' && !canAskAgain) {
                permissionAlert();
            }
        }
    };

    return (
        <AudioContext.Provider value={{audioFiles: audioFiles, dataProvaider}}>
            {children}
        </AudioContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

quando tento executar o código ele lança o seguinte erro no terminal:

```
 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'y' of undefined

This error is located at:
    in RecyclerListView
    in TabOneScreen
    in Unknown (created by Route(index))
    in Route (created by Route(index))
    in LocationProvider (created by Route(index))
    in Route(index) (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by BottomTabView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Screen)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Background)
    in Background (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by BottomTabView)
    in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by MaybeScreen)
    in MaybeScreen (created by BottomTabView)
    in RNSScreenContainer (created by ScreenContainer)
    in ScreenContainer (created by MaybeScreenContainer)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (created by BottomTabView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by BottomTabView)
    in BottomTabView (created by BottomTabNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by BottomTabNavigator)
    in BottomTabNavigator
    in Unknown (created by TabLayout)
    in TabLayout
    in Unknown (created by Route((tabs)))
    in Route (created by Route((tabs)))
    in LocationProvider (created by Route((tabs)))
    in Route((tabs)) (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by DebugContainer)
    in DebugContainer (created by MaybeNestedStack)
    in MaybeNestedStack (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SceneView)
    in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by ScreenStack)
    in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
    in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
    in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in NativeStackNavigator
    in Unknown (created by RootLayoutNav)
    in ThemeProvider (created by RootLayoutNav)
    in RootLayoutNav (created by RootLayout)
    in AudioProvaider (created by RootLayout)
    in RootLayout
    in Try
    in Unknown
    in Unknown (created by Route())
    in Route (created by Route())
    in LocationProvider (created by Route())
    in Route() (created by RootRoute)
    in RootRoute (created by ContextNavigator)
    in InitialRootStateProvider (created by ContextNavigator)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by NavigationContainer)
    in NavigationContainer (created by ContextNavigator)
    in RootRouteNodeProvider (created by ContextNavigator)
    in ContextNavigator (created by ExpoRoot)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by ExpoRoot)
    in RNGestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandler)
    in GestureHandler (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot (created by App)
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App) (created by ErrorOverlay)
    in ErrorToastContainer (created by ErrorOverlay)
    in ErrorOverlay
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
```

se alguem tiver alguma ideia para resolver esse erro eu agradeço